# Constant check for variable change

Tags: ios, swift, while-loop, timer

Would there be a way to continuously check if a variable has changed in swift?

I have tried a basic timer idea, which is not very smart as it did not work precisely down to the millisecond of allowed disruption and is probably highly unpredictable and glitchy. Would there be a way to design such a checker? Ideally, could it be created within a waiting method such as this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
})
```

What I mean with this is that while this waiting timer is waiting, could it have a sort of exception breaking it and executing a different code if a specified variable has changed?

Comment: Have you looked at using a `didSet` observer?

Comment: In what context do you need this?

Comment: I apologize for being offline for this long: I am looking to make a second view controller be prepared (with the checking algorithm) when a variable changes (affected by the first view controller through the beginning of editing a searchbar.text), so that I can change certain events in the secondviewcontroller while editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can edit the property yourself (i.e. you wrote the property yourself), you can consider using a `didSet` block:

```
var someProperty: String {
    didSet {
        print("Got a new value: \(newValue)")
    }
}
```

If the property is not written by you but is exposed to Objective-C, you can do some Key-value Observing:

```
@objc class MyClass : NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var someProperty: String = "Hello"
}

let obj = MyClass()
obj.observe(\.someProperty) { (myClass, value) in
    print("Got a new value: \(myClass.someProperty)")
}
obj.someProperty = "Changed!"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is key-value observing. There is Foundation support for KVO of NSObject properties, and there is support for native Swift KVO in Swift 4.